# Google calendar api user defined id using php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am creating hundreds of calendars and than assigning users. I need to update that calendars regularly so I need to create custom ID's for each calendar.  No matter what I use it comes back as an invalid ID

Below is my Script in PHP

```
 require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Assignments Calendar');
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . __DIR__ . '/Assignment_Calendars-701dce094981.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
        Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)
));

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);
$calendarServiceAccount = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
 $calendarId="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
$newCalendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
$newCalendar->setSummary("testing");
$newCalendar->setTimeZone('America/Chicago');
$newCalendar->setId($calendarId);
$calendar = $calendarServiceAccount->calendars->insert($newCalendar);
```

My Error message is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid resource id value."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid resource id value."
 }
}
```

No matter what I change the $calendarId to it get the same error.  If I remove 
$newCalendar->setId($calendarId); it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign a custom ID, the ID of a calendar is defined by the API. See [API reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert).

You will have to create the calendar, read the $calendar->id value after the `insert` call and store it somewhere to link it to the user by any means.

Comment: Darn. That sucks. I thought since the Google PHP client includes a setId method it would work.